# XSLT list top 50

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Following my previous question: [Sort complex XML structure by nested attribute using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873736/sort-complex-xml-structure-by-nested-attribute-using-xslt) (Was poorly setup) apologies.

I was curious how you would go about only listing the top 10 Locations of Standard sales.

Can this be used inside apply-templates as i am having difficulty using it

```
<xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 10">
```

Comment: It isn't necessary at all to do a 2-pass processing as done in the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a simple, complete, solution, which is a single-pass**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="pTopN" select="2"/>

    <xsl:template match="CompanyStats">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="CompanyLocation">
                <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="UserContent/StandardSales/Sales" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CompanyLocation">
      <xsl:if test="not(position() > $pTopN)">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (containing three `CompanyLocation` elements):

```
<Company>
    <CompanyStats>
        <CompanyLocation id="London">
            <OfficeID>1</OfficeID>
            <Totalworkers>20</Totalworkers>
            <NoCleaners>2</NoCleaners>
            <TopSales>
                <UserID>4</UserID>
                <Sales>43</Sales>
                <Description> Highest sales this quater</Description>
            </TopSales>
            <LowestSales>
                <UserID>12</UserID>
                <Sales>26</Sales>
                <Description> Lowest sales this quater</Description>
            </LowestSales>
            <UserContent>
                <ID>4</ID>
                <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
                <Surname>Black</Surname>
                <StartDate>11/11/2011</StartDate>
                <StandardSales>
                    <SSID>0</SSID>
                    <Sales>64</Sales>
                    <SalesManager>Steve Hewitt</SalesManager>
                </StandardSales>
                <BusinessSales>
                    <BSID>0</BSID>
                    <Sales>64</Sales>
                    <SalesManager>Steve Hewitt</SalesManager>
                </BusinessSales>
            </UserContent>
        </CompanyLocation>
        <CompanyLocation id="Paris">
            <OfficeID>1</OfficeID>
            <Totalworkers>20</Totalworkers>
            <NoCleaners>2</NoCleaners>
            <TopSales>
                <UserID>4</UserID>
                <Sales>43</Sales>
                <Description> Highest sales this quater</Description>
            </TopSales>
            <LowestSales>
                <UserID>12</UserID>
                <Sales>26</Sales>
                <Description> Lowest sales this quater</Description>
            </LowestSales>
            <UserContent>
                <ID>4</ID>
                <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
                <Surname>Black</Surname>
                <StartDate>11/11/2011</StartDate>
                <StandardSales>
                    <SSID>0</SSID>
                    <Sales>122</Sales>
                    <SalesManager>Steve Hewitt</SalesManager>
                </StandardSales>
                <BusinessSales>
                    <BSID>0</BSID>
                    <Sales>64</Sales>
                    <SalesManager>Steve Hewitt</SalesManager>
                </BusinessSales>
            </UserContent>
        </CompanyLocation>
        <CompanyLocation id="Berlin">
            <OfficeID>1</OfficeID>
            <Totalworkers>20</Totalworkers>
            <NoCleaners>2</NoCleaners>
            <TopSales>
                <UserID>4</UserID>
                <Sales>43</Sales>
                <Description> Highest sales this quater</Description>
            </TopSales>
            <LowestSales>
                <UserID>12</UserID>
                <Sales>26</Sales>
                <Description> Lowest sales this quater</Description>
            </LowestSales>
            <UserContent>
                <ID>4</ID>
                <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
                <Surname>Black</Surname>
                <StartDate>11/11/2011</StartDate>
                <StandardSales>
                    <SSID>0</SSID>
                    <Sales>12</Sales>
                    <SalesManager>Steve Hewitt</SalesManager>
                </StandardSales>
                <BusinessSales>
                    <BSID>0</BSID>
                    <Sales>64</Sales>
                    <SalesManager>Steve Hewitt</SalesManager>
                </BusinessSales>
            </UserContent>
        </CompanyLocation>
    </CompanyStats>
</Company>
```

**the top (after the sorting) two of these are produced to the output**:

```
<CompanyStats>
   <CompanyLocation id="Paris">
      <OfficeID>1</OfficeID>
      <Totalworkers>20</Totalworkers>
      <NoCleaners>2</NoCleaners>
      <TopSales>
         <UserID>4</UserID>
         <Sales>43</Sales>
         <Description> Highest sales this quater</Description>
      </TopSales>
      <LowestSales>
         <UserID>12</UserID>
         <Sales>26</Sales>
         <Description> Lowest sales this quater</Description>
      </LowestSales>
      <UserContent>
         <ID>4</ID>
         <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
         <Surname>Black</Surname>
         <StartDate>11/11/2011</StartDate>
         <StandardSales>
            <SSID>0</SSID>
            <Sales>122</Sales>
            <SalesManager>Steve Hewitt</SalesManager>
         </StandardSales>
         <BusinessSales>
            <BSID>0</BSID>
            <Sales>64</Sales>
            <SalesManager>Steve Hewitt</SalesManager>
         </BusinessSales>
      </UserContent>
   </CompanyLocation>
   <CompanyLocation id="London">
      <OfficeID>1</OfficeID>
      <Totalworkers>20</Totalworkers>
      <NoCleaners>2</NoCleaners>
      <TopSales>
         <UserID>4</UserID>
         <Sales>43</Sales>
         <Description> Highest sales this quater</Description>
      </TopSales>
      <LowestSales>
         <UserID>12</UserID>
         <Sales>26</Sales>
         <Description> Lowest sales this quater</Description>
      </LowestSales>
      <UserContent>
         <ID>4</ID>
         <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
         <Surname>Black</Surname>
         <StartDate>11/11/2011</StartDate>
         <StandardSales>
            <SSID>0</SSID>
            <Sales>64</Sales>
            <SalesManager>Steve Hewitt</SalesManager>
         </StandardSales>
         <BusinessSales>
            <BSID>0</BSID>
            <Sales>64</Sales>
            <SalesManager>Steve Hewitt</SalesManager>
         </BusinessSales>
      </UserContent>
   </CompanyLocation>
</CompanyStats>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The wanted number of top elements to process is specified in the global/external parameter `$pTopN`. In this way, when this parameter is set outside of the transformation, the transformation can be used for any wanted number, without any modification.
2. The key moment is in the `xsl:apply-templates`, which has an `xsl:sort` child. This causes the template(s) to be applied to a sorted node-list.
3. Inside the matching template there is a single condition that compares the `position()` to the `$pTopN` parameter and the processing is performed only if the current position hasn't exceeded that number.

Answer (score 2):

Define this in predicate, e.g.:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() &lt;= 10]" />
```

Comment: perfectly elegant answer thanks. I will up-vote this when i can

Answer (score 2):

well, normaly i would do this in two steps. But in this simple case you can use a variable as temporary step. change the template you got by your first question in this way:

```
<xsl:template match="CompanyStats">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <!-- sorting of the CompanyLocation in a temporary variable -->
        <xsl:variable name="CompanyLocationSorted">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="CompanyLocation">
                <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="UserContent/StandardSales/Sales" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- copies just the first 10 of the sorted CompanyLocation-->
        <xsl:copy-of select="$CompanyLocationSorted/CompanyLocation[position() &lt;= 10]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Well that saved me working out how to implement it to incorporate the sorted list. Thanks!